# calling rnorm with a matrix of means and a matrix of standard deviations

Tags: r, matrix, normal-distribution

I have two matrices of dimension n*p, one containing means and one containing sds.

I want to do something like rnorm(1, means, sds) and get a new matrix n*p so that each cell results from rnorm(1, means[i,j], sds[i,j]).

How do I do this without looping?

I looked at functions from the apply family, sweep and outer, but despite the solution probably being a simple one-liner, I can't figure it out.

```
means=matrix(1:12,ncol=4)
sds=round(matrix(runif(12,0.1,0.2),ncol=4),2)
```

Comment: @jogo, post as answer? the other way to do this, if you already have a matrix `m` that's got the right dimensions, is `m[] <- rnorm(...)`

Comment: Thank you. Before this I used a vector of sds and called mapply, which stupidly had me thinking I had to do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `rnorm()` can take a vector in the parameter `mean=` and a vector in the parameter `sd=` as you want:

```
matrix(rnorm(length(means), mean=means, sd=sds), nrow(means))
```

If you already have a matrix `m` with the right dimensions then you can do:

```
m[] <- rnorm(length(means), mean=means, sd=sds)
```

*(thx to @BenBolker for the comment)*